# Does Vishnu purana mention anything about kalki avatar?

Tags: vishnu-purana, kalki

Kindly provide links to the verses if Vishnu Purana mentions anything about Kalki avatar.
I know Bhagavata Purana does mention kalki avatar.

Comment: Ganesha Gita mentions a very similar figure to Kalki, i.e. grey silver skin, mounted on the top of the horse, an incarnation of Ganesha in the end of Kaliyuga.

Answer (score 1):

> When the practices taught by the Vedas and the institutes of law shall
> nearly have ceased, and the close of the Kali age shall be nigh, a
> portion of that divine being who exists of his own spiritual nature in
> the character of Brahma, and who is the beginning and the end, and who
> comprehends all things, shall descend upon earth: **he will be born in
> the family of Viṣṇuyaśas, an eminent Brahman of Sambhala village, as
> Kalki**, endowed with the eight superhuman faculties. By his
> irresistible might **he will destroy all the Mlecchas and thieves, and
> all whose minds are devoted to iniquity**. He will then reestablish
> righteousness upon earth; and the minds of those who live at the end
> of the Kali age shall be awakened, and shall be as pellucid as
> crystal. The men who are thus changed by virtue of that peculiar time
> shall be as the seeds of human beings, and shall give birth to a race
> who shall follow the laws of the Krita age, or age of purity.

- Chapter XXIV, book IV, Vishnu Purana.